# Syntax for MySQL LOAD XML "SET" parameter?

Tags: mysql, xml

I am trying to load an xml file containing timestamp entries in the "20120924 22:12" format into MySql.

I am using the LOAD XML feature.  Of course it's not working because MySQL is expecting "2012-09-24 22:12".  If I was using LOAD FILE I would add

```
SET tmstmp = str_to_date(@var3, '%Y%m%d %h:i%')}
```

to my command, where the tmstmp data is in column 3 of the tile.  So for XML I'd like to use

```
SET tmstmp = str_to_date(@tmstmp, '%Y%m%d %h:i%')}
```

where tmstmp is the tag containing my timestamp data.  But this doesn't work.  @tmstmp is empty.  How do I access tags in SET statements under LOAD XML?  The MySQL documentation just defers to the LOAD FILE documentation but it's not there of course.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong (`i%` must be `%i`). So, change `'%Y%m%d %h:i%'` with `'%Y%m%d %h:%i'` and try to load data again.

Also `%h` should be `%H` because you use 24-hour format.